# prefill username input field on roundcube website

Tags: google-chrome

I want to achieve this: when I open specific url (there is roundcube login page) in Chrome on desktop, I want to have username prefilled (or at least when I start typing "h" it should show me ability to use username hello@something.dom - this way I have it on Android in chrome).

Any idea how to do this please and set it up in chrome on desktop? (I do not want to save username and password in Password settings in Chrome, I just need to get ability to choose from previously used or stored prefill value, so I do not need to type it again and again many times per day)

Thank you!

Comment: My web hoster provides a Roundcube with a custom *domain* field and I'd also like to prefill this one

Comment: The *domain* field turned out be just a customized label for the `host` input which could be prefilled by passing the `_host` GET parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually done in 2010 as part of GitHub issue [3044](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/issues/3044).

You can append the GET parameters `_user` or `_host` to prefill these fields. It's not implemented for the password field for obvious reasons.

https://mail.mycompany.example/?_user=hello%40something.dom